# How do I include a JavaScript library without using a module?

Tags: 7, javascript

Note: I'm very new at using Drupal, so I may be missing something.

I've searched high and low, but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

I've got a custom Drupal theme based on Zen, and I want to include a jQuery plugin (specifically, [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)) into a page that needs it (I'm using Panels and Views to create custom landing pages). Frankly, I'd be happy even if I had to include it on the entire site.

I looked at [JavaScript Libraries Manager](http://drupal.org/project/javascript_libraries), [jQuery Plugins Module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_plugin), but these didn't seem to be able to include CSS or images, which Lightbox requires.

I tried placed the script and CSS/image files in my theme's folder, and then using the following in `mytheme_preprocess_page()` in my theme's `template.php`:

```
$options = array('group' => JS_THEME);
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . "/js/jquery.lightbox.js', $options);
```

This loads the JavaScript file OK, but it doesn't function correctly because it's looking for the images at the web root `/` (and I didn't include the CSS file, anyway).

I saw an example of [using `hook_library()`](http://drupal.org/node/756722), and this looks promising as it allows specification of CSS files as well, but I'm not sure where/how to include this setup code.

Also, I realize that there is a Lightbox module, but because the way that my content types and views are done, I can't add `rel="lightbox"` to the anchors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need to hook the theme system or deploy a module, why not try including the paths to Light Box's dependencies in one or more of your template files?

Better yet add the CSS and JS file paths (relative to the theme folder) to your theme's info file.

[Stylesheets](http://drupal.org/node/171205#stylesheets)

[Scripts](http://drupal.org/node/171205#scripts)

Comment: I'm having a funny problem: the CSS file worked fine when adding it to the .info file, but the script isn't being added correctly when I reference it like `scripts[] = js/jquery.lightbox.js`. The strange thing is that if I rename the script to just `script.js` and update the .info file accordingly, the script gets loaded correctly...

Comment: My guess, off hand, is that whatever parses the info file doesn't understand two periods in the js file name.  Maybe try renaming the file and specifying jquery_lightbox.js and see if the file is resolved that way.